# Universal Pair value type for intent extras

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin

Quite simple issue: is it possible to find universal Intent extra type for second Pair argument (String, Int, Bundle etc)?

```
inline fun <reified T : Activity> Context.startActivity(vararg params: Pair<String, ?>) {
    val intent = Intent(this, T::class.java)
    params.forEach { intent.putExtra(it.first, it.second) }
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

Thanks

Comment: If I understand it correctly, You want to find out what type of value is in the `intent` `bundle`? Can't you just use `get` method which will return `Object` and then look do `getClass().getSimpleName()` on that `Object` to find the class. You can even use `instanceof`to do something by type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this isn't possible with the current language features and Android API.

If you dive into the source of [Anko](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko), you'll find that in the end they resort to the trivial and somewhat ugly solution as well. (For the higher level public functions you're supposed to use, they use `vararg params: Pair<String, Any?>`, and then delegate to the following.)

```
@JvmStatic
private fun fillIntentArguments(intent: Intent, params: Array<out Pair<String, Any?>>) {
    params.forEach {
        val value = it.second
        when (value) {
            null -> intent.putExtra(it.first, null as Serializable?)
            is Int -> intent.putExtra(it.first, value)
            is Long -> intent.putExtra(it.first, value)
            is CharSequence -> intent.putExtra(it.first, value)
            is String -> intent.putExtra(it.first, value)
            is Float -> intent.putExtra(it.first, value)
            is Double -> intent.putExtra(it.first, value)
            is Char -> intent.putExtra(it.first, value)
            is Short -> intent.putExtra(it.first, value)
            is Boolean -> intent.putExtra(it.first, value)
            is Serializable -> intent.putExtra(it.first, value)
            is Bundle -> intent.putExtra(it.first, value)
            is Parcelable -> intent.putExtra(it.first, value)
            is Array<*> -> when {
                value.isArrayOf<CharSequence>() -> intent.putExtra(it.first, value)
                value.isArrayOf<String>() -> intent.putExtra(it.first, value)
                value.isArrayOf<Parcelable>() -> intent.putExtra(it.first, value)
                else -> throw AnkoException("Intent extra ${it.first} has wrong type ${value.javaClass.name}")
            }
            is IntArray -> intent.putExtra(it.first, value)
            is LongArray -> intent.putExtra(it.first, value)
            is FloatArray -> intent.putExtra(it.first, value)
            is DoubleArray -> intent.putExtra(it.first, value)
            is CharArray -> intent.putExtra(it.first, value)
            is ShortArray -> intent.putExtra(it.first, value)
            is BooleanArray -> intent.putExtra(it.first, value)
            else -> throw AnkoException("Intent extra ${it.first} has wrong type ${value.javaClass.name}")
        }
        return@forEach
    }
}
```

You can find the file here: https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/blob/683115f93ca6b0ed36ab36f3814dbc0da0abe7d3/anko/library/static/common/src/Internals.kt#L143

Comment: Didn't even look into Anko source, thank you for notice

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. Take a look at the [implementation of the putExtra() methods](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/content/Intent.java#7109).

They don't use polymorphism to determine the type of operation to be performed, you really need to invoke the method with the correct type signature for its second argument.